# What is val it in sml?

Tags: sml

I have an example looks like this.

```
type int_pair = int * int;

val it:int_pair = (1,1);
```

I don't quite understand what does val it means and in what condition we will use val.

Does it mean we are assigning value to the int_pair it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `it` is bound to the value `(1, 1)` of type `int_pair`; see [documentation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/core/decls.htm).